# Valgrind quits when application becomes daemonized

Tags: c++, linux, daemon, valgrind

I have a C++ app which is a Linux daemon (I use a single fork to make it daemon) based on the code from this daemon example http://www.itp.uzh.ch/~dpotter/howto/daemonize . I'm trying to find memory leaks with valgrind:

```
/usr/bin/valgrind.bin --suppressions=/usr/lib/valgrind/debian-libc6-dbg.supp --tool=memcheck --child-silent-after-fork=no --trace-children=yes --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes /usr/sbin/<my daemon>
```

But valgrind exits immediately after initial process dies while application still works in child process. 
If I comment out code which exits initial process then valgrind continues working. But it's not a clean solution.
How can I keep valgrind working without it?

Comment: Many daemon-type programs have command line options to tell it if it should "daemonize" or not. Maybe you could do something similar, i.e. let it daemonize as default but have flag that tells it not to?

Comment: I prefer not to create special application configuration for valgrind and wanted to debug app as is. But if it's the only way then I'll do it

Comment: Why u use /usr/bin/vagrind.bin? - /usr/bin/valgrind is a wrapper script and setup some environment variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Valgrind's faq says specifically that it can't be attached to an already running process. I suppose all their instrumentation set up is also lost on fork().
They do mention a workaround that sounds very complicated ([here](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.attach)) but i think it will add more unwanted complexity than just not daemonizing.